# Initialize an empty list of the shape/structure of a given list without numpy

Tags: python, list

Given a list `A` with `n` rows each having `m` columns each.
Is there a one liner to create an empty list `B` with same structure (`n` rows each with `m` components)?

Numpy lists can be created/reshaped. Does the python in-built `list` type support such an argument?

Comment: `[[None for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Individual elements can be inserted or deleted, but there is no equivalent reshape function.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Can 'm' and 'n' be replaced by something general that derives the shape of list `A`

Comment: @vvy `len(A[0])` and `len(A)`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

n = len(A)
m = len(A[0])


B = [[0 for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]
```

EDIT:

To make it a one-liner:

```
B = [[0 for x in range(len(A[0])] for y in range(len(A))]
```

EDIT:

As suggested by Jblasco  in the comments, this is an even nicer way of doing it:

```
 B = [[0 for i in line] for line in A]
```

(All credit to Jblasco for that solution!!)

Comment: Thanks. It isn't exactly a one-liner, but explains the basic idea. @PatrickHaugh's answer would be a refined version of your answer.

Comment: To make it even simpler, I'd suggest:  B = [[0 for ii in line] for line in A]

Comment: @Jblasco ah thats awesome! Nice one! :)

Comment: You came up with the answer, I just cleaned it a little bit! :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use: B=[[None]*m]*n

It creates a list of n rows of m columns of None.

Comment: Have you tried, after doing this, printing the following?   id(B[0]) == id(B[1]) or changing the first element of one of the rows?